# Ruby error with simple ActiveRecord.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing some rake taks to find objects with a simple find method as follows:

```
skill = Mastery.find(:first, :conditions =>  [ "tree = ? AND tier = ? AND column = ?",
              i.to_s,
              row_index.to_s,
              col_index.to_s
            ])
```

This works fine locally. However, when I deploy to my production environment the server fails and responds with this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column = '1') LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT  `masteries`.* FROM `masteries`  WHERE (tree = '1' AND tier = '1' AND column = '1') LIMIT 1
```

I'm using the `mysql2` gem in my rails app. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using sqlite in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that "column" is a reserved word on that particular version of MySQL? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

It could be the case that MySQL is giving an error because you're using a reserved word as a column name.

Comment: Ah, interesting thought. I'll give it a shot!